# Problems with division using a constant in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am displaying recorded values of pressure.

I always store pressure as PSI in my database, knowing that I can convert it to BAR by dividing by 14.5

So, I have a table called `configuration` and one called `measurements` and I want so say
`SELECT pressure DIV my_db.configuration.conversion_factor AS pressure FROM my_db.measurements WHERE ...` and my front-end s/w will set `my_db.configuration.conversion_factor` to either 1 or 14.5 as appropriate.

But I am getting an error `unknown column 'my_db.configuration.conversion_factor' in 'filed list'`.

Since I am cut/pasting, I doubt that it is a spelling error - so what is wrong with my query?

---

[Update]
@JimGarrison set me on the correct path. What I needed was

`SELECT pressure DIV (SELECT conversion_factor FROM my_db.configuration WHERE 1) AS pressure FROM my_db.measurements WHERE ...`

Note: I add that `WHERE 1` for anyone reading this question in future; I only have a single row in the configuration table, so I don't need a `WHERE` - but you might ..

Thanks, Jim

Comment: If there's only one row in the configuration table, then you don't need any WHERE clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't refer to a field in a second table like that.  `my_db.configuration` is a table with rows and columns.  How does SQL know which row you want to use?

What I think you're looking for is

```
select pressure div (select conversion_factor from my_db.configuration where <???>=<???>) ...
```

where `<???>` is where you'd put the key column name and value for the entry you want to use from the conversion_factor table.

Answer (score 1):

You have to list all the tables you want to reference in a FROM clause — in this case, *the* FROM clause.

```
SELECT pressure DIV my_db.configuration.conversion_factor AS pressure
  FROM my_db.measurements
 CROSS JOIN my_db.configuration
 WHERE ...
```

The CROSS JOIN is used assuming there's just one row in your configuration table.  It doesn't require a join condition.

Or you can use a sub-select as [Jim Garrison](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18157/jim-garrison) suggests in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13619657/15168).  It's probably cleaner.  But note that he referenced the configuration table in a FROM clause.